# How to bind javafx class with fxml file

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have created TreeTableView by coding. Then I created 2 fxml files. one(overview.fxml) has splitpane(left side is label andand button and right side nothing) and the other(RootLayout.fxml) one with a menu bar which wraps the first one. How can i set bind my treetable view which is in main class to the right side of splitpane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this *sorry for the earlier blunder*

```
SplitPane sp = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/overview.fxml"));   
StackPane container = new StackPane(); 
container.getChildren().add(YourCreatedTreeViewNode);
sp.getItems().add(container);
sp.setDividerPositions(0.3f, 0.6f, 0.9f); // you can tweak it any how
```

SplitPane two or more sides, each separated by a divider, which can be dragged by the user to give more space to one of the sides, resulting in the other side shrinking by an equal amount. Nodes needs to be placed inside a layout container before they are added into the SplitPane. If the node is not inside a layout container the maximum and minimum position of the divider will be the maximum and minimum size of the content. 
Safe to say you just add your nodes to the `SplitPane` and it will do the positioning..

hope it helps

Comment: i get The method getChildren() from the type Parent is not visible when i try to sp.getChildren....    What is meant by theplaceyouwanttoaddTableView? where should i use it? thanks